# GAE Modules - Multiple Runtimes

Tags: google-app-engine

With the release of GAE Modules, currently our app has been segmented on multiple module to better handle the requests.

We current have one PHP GAE APP with 4 modules running PHP, and another app engine with 1 module (technically 0 module), running Python.

Is it okay to merge the python app under the PHP one using the module and set a different runtime for it ?

Comment: It's completely OK to use different languages on different modules.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have multiple runtimes in an app engine project (As Dimitry also mentioned in his comment), where each runtime is at a module level:

> Modules can be configured to use different runtimes and to operate with different performance settings.

Source: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/